# C# deserialize JSON that uses for SOME fields empty objects as null

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm using Microsoft's JsonSerializer to deserialize some JSON.

I read some answers about formats that treated "" as NULL but surprisingly none about using empty objects {} as NULL.
Which leads me to hoping there is an even easier option than writing a custom converter.

I receive a Json in the format

```
{
   "obj1":{  //required, must be defined and contain all its props
      //prop1
      //prop2
   },
   "obj2":{  //optional, can either contain all its props or be NULL (be a NULL value)
      //prop3
      //prop4
   },
   "obj3":{  //optional, can either contain all its props or none (be an empty object {})      
      //prop4
      //prop5
   }
}
```

i can deserialize into something like

```
public record MyModel {
   public Obj1Type obj1 {get; set;}  
   public Obj2Type? obj2 {get; set;} // using nullable type should do the trick
   public Obj3Type obj3 {get; set;}  //<-- how can i define this one..?
}

class Obj1Type {
   //prop1 get/set
   //prop2 get/set
}

class Obj2Type {
   //prop3 get/set
   //prop4 get/set
}

class Obj3Type {
   //???
}
```

but what about the third kind? how can i make it accept either {} or a specific class?

Comment: "optional" for the "obj3" is not the right term, to me. Based on what you say, that field must be valued all the time, but its content allows a two-way schema. To me, as you defined the "obj3" property in MyModel is correct.

Comment: @MarioVernari and how i make the JsonSerializer enforce such a schema? If i ask it to deserialize into a class and the JSON holds and empty object it will throw an exception

Comment: What does `be an empty object` mean? That the properties will be null? Or have default values? You may not have to change anything or you may have to make the properties nullable, depending on the actual requirement

Comment: `and the JSON holds and empty object it will throw an exception` post an actual *executable* example and the actual full exception thrown by the serializer. You may only have to change `int` to `int?` if `empty` means `null properties`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos with empty object i mean the JSON property will hold empty brakets, an object with no properties inside. "prop"={},

Comment: That's not what I asked. What do you want `Obj3Type` to contain if the json string contains `"obj3":{}`? By default [the deserializer *ignores* missing fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/missing-members) so why are you getting an exception at all? Post an actual executable example

Comment: "Which leads me to hoping there is an even easier option than writing a custom converter." You have a very specific requirement, so a custom converter is what is needed, after all it exists precisely to accomodate such unusal requirements.